# No module named 'airflow.providers'

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, cloud, google-cloud-composer

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/dags/Test_dag/bigquery_dag.py] No module named 'airflow.providers'
This is error I am getting while running the dag in airflow.

I imported airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery to use bigQueryOperator.
I created empty table and needed to load the data from cloud composer.
Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator



# Define default_args
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 4, 20)
   
}

# Create a DAG instance

with DAG(
    dag_id = "dag_bigquery",
    default_args= default_args,
   # schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup = False

) as dag :
    
    # create empty table task
    create_table_task = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        project_id = "projectid",
        dataset_id = "datasetid",
        table_id= "himani-dummy-table",
        schema_fields=[
        {'name':'Brand_Id',"type": 'INT64'},
        {'name':'Brand_Code','type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'Brand_Name','type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'Entity_Id','type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'Entity_InsertedAt','type':'DATE'},
        {'name':'Entity_InsertedBy',"type": 'INT64'},
        {'name':'Entity_UpdatedAt','type':'DATE'},
        {'name':'Entity_UpdatedBy','type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'Entity_DivisionId','type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'Entity_OemId','type':'STRING'},
        ],
        bigquery_conn_id ='my-bigquery-connection'
       
    )


create_table_task
```

Comment: could you pls show us the install command for the apache-airflow-providers-google?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to both install

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

and

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

Then you should be able to import the module :)

Comment: I have already imported these package. But still getting the error on airflow dag

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing a similiar error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the packages through the Composer environment GUI and seeing if that works? [image: Composer env GUI]